# If table checkbox is checked, uncheck other table checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, this, checked

I have numerous tables, and when a checkbox is checked in one - all other tables should clear. You can check any number of checkboxes in this table, but only able to check checkboxes in one table at a time.
How would I go about doing this? I want to avoid using ids if possible because I have 8 tables.

http://jsfiddle.net/69o3e5y4/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {

});
```

Comment: It sounds like radio buttons would be perfect for this. Is there a reason you dont want to use them instead?

Comment: @microsby0: "You can check any number of checkboxes in this table"

Comment: @DarkFalcon ah thank you, I did not notice that part. You could use classes, one class per table by chance? Its a little better than ids

Comment: How could you go about using classes/ids? I don't want a long string of if this is not table1, table2, table3, table4, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can :

1. get the containing table `$(this).closest("table")`
2. then get all other tables : `$("table").not($table)`
3. finally, uncheck all inputs from these tables : `... .prop("checked", false)`.

This should give some code like this :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
    var $table = $(this).closest("table");    // Current table

    $("table").not($table)                    // Other tables
        .find("input[type=checkbox]:checked") // Checked input of these tables
        .prop("checked", false);              // Uncheck them
});
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/69o3e5y4/2/

Comment: Furthermore, for each checkbox checked, can we log the .closest('td').next().html() being the name? So if only one is checked, "red" but if more than one add a comma "red, blue" and the last word should not have a comma "red, blue, ".

Comment: got it. $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
var $table = $(this).closest("table");
    $("table").not($table).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop("checked", false);
    
var chklist = "";
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
    chklist += (chklist=="" ? sThisVal : ", " + sThisVal);
});
console.log (chklist);
});

Answer (score 0):

This jquery works without any ids:

```
$('table').each(function(index){    
        $(this).find('input').each(function()
        {
           $(this).on('click', function () {          
            clearThisTablesCheckboxes(index);
           });

        });
 });

function clearThisTablesCheckboxes(position){
     $('table').each(function(index){ 
            $(this).find('input').each(function()
            {
                if(position != index)
                {
                    var prop=false;
                    $(this).prop('checked',prop);
               }
            });   
     });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/69o3e5y4/8/

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this, but I would use classes.  So all your checkboxes in Table1 would be class "Table1", all checkboxes in Table2 would be in class "Table2", etc.

Then, within the event handler you already have, you can iterate through each checkbox on the page, and uncheck all of them if their class doesn't match the one that was clicked.

For example (again, not tested):

```
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                var CurrentClass = $(this).prop("class");

                $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop("class") != CurrentClass)
                        $(this).prop("checked", false);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: -1 `.prop('class')`? What if the checkbox has more than one class?

Comment: prop("class") doesn't return a list - it returns a string (space delimited).  If his checkboxes all have the same 5 classes, he could add a sixth (the table name) and this code will work.  If the checkboxes have no classes, he could add one (the table name) and this code will work.

Comment: I understand. There are just too many variables (`if`'s) so this does not sound like an ideal solution.